# Append string to previous line if certain condition in python

Tags: python

I have csv file with single column, in some cases the last value gets more space and create new row, here I need to find out and append it to the previous line

for eg : [image: excel file]

my python code :

```
with open("01.csv", 'r+') as file:
    text = str()
    for line in file:
        if line[0:3] == "2021":
           text = "{} {}".format(text, line.strip())
        else:
             text = "{}\n{}".format(text, line.strip())
            
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(text[1:])
```

How to remove || this in last and append next line to it in all occurrence.

[image]

Line no 10 to be appended to line no 9 and line no 21 to be appended to line no 20 nd so on..

Comment: FYI, `line[0:3]` only gives 3 characters, so `line[0:3] == "2021"` will always be `False`.

Comment: That looks more like a pipe delimited file than a csv.

Comment: @NicholasHunter I am having this in csv file only

Comment: @Joffan It is used to remove spaces in start

Comment: @Joffan Yes it has to do i have done removing the spaces and its posted after removing

Comment: @Joffan yes I then thats not the issue here i need to append the line which moved to next line to the previous line

Comment: If you have a test that doesn't work, even an otherwise valid solution will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "append next line" if you haven't seen it yet. Your solution has to know that all appends are complete before otherwise acting on a line, which means you need to buffer the next line.

I think you're trying to re-compose the whole file in `text` as you go, which isn't a great model for file handling. And if your test were working, the actions are actually the wrong way around - you want to include the newline when "20" starts the line. I suggest that instead you write to another new file or simply correct the issue on the fly as below.

```py
with open("01.csv", 'r+') as file:
    complete_line = None
    for line in file:
        if complete_line is None:
           initial_action()
           complete_line = line
        elif line[0:2] == "20": # compatible with next 79 years
           act_on(complete_line)
           complete_line = line
        else:
           complete_line += line

    act_on(complete_line)
```

where `intial_action` and `act_on` are functions for you to implement.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\xml2csv.py", line 8, in <module>
    complete_line += line
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
This is the i m getting now and it shows act_on as undefined

Comment: I didn't get the complete line because it differ line by line

Comment: @SabariLogesh I don't understand that response. Is there a header line in the file?

Comment: yes Its a single column and i have updated my question with screen shot of that csv file